# How To Center Align Menu Through CSS?

Tags: css

I want to center align the search,logo and cart through CSS, but I am unable to do so, if I change the margin all the alignment is disturbed. How can I center align search, logo and cart?

**css:**

```
.logo {

float:left;
width:370px;
margin-bottom: 10px;}

#search {
float:left;
width:235px;
text-align: left;
margin-bottom: 10px; }

#top-cart {
text-align: right;
float:right;
position: relative;
padding:1px 20px 5px 0;
background: url(images/shopping-bag.png) no-repeat top right;
width:280px;
line-height: 16px;}
#top-cart > a{
    color:#818181;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="containerInner clearfix">
<header id="header">
<div id="search">
<div id="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></div>
<?php get_search_form(); ?></div>
<div class="logo">
                <?php $logoimg = etheme_get_option('logo'); ?>
                <?php if($logoimg): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $logoimg ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?>" /></a>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" class="logo-text"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>
                <?php endif ;?>                   
            </div>
<div class="cart-wrapper">

            </div>
```

I've tried to use `margin-left:auto;` and `margin-right:auto;` but failed.

Comment: Your HTML code is PHP code, on the back-end. This isn't what is received by our browsers. Please post the HTML code

Comment: use margin:0 auto; in wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the HTML you provided matches up with the CSS (missing pieces?) but typically the best way to center stuff horizontally is to remove the floats and make each item `display:inline-block`. Then make the wrapper `text-align: center`. For instance:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="search"></div>
  <div class="cart"></div>
</div>

#wrapper { text-align: center; }
.logo, .search, .cart { display: inline-block; }
```

Hope this helps, if not please provide a pastebin or more code - thanks!